# NHibernate Aggregate Subquery

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a problem with NHibernate that I don't seem to be able to find a simple way around.

I have the following database:

Game: ID, Score, Match_ID

Match: ID

A match consists of 3 games.

I want to find out what the maximum Match score is, so the following SQL would do the trick:

```
select max(a.total) from 
  (select Match.ID, sum(Game.Score) as total 
     from Game inner join Match
     on Game.Match_ID = Match.ID
     group by Match.ID) a
```

In NHibernate, this appears to be a bit trickier. Apparently, HQL does not allow subqueries in the from clause, so I can't really use this.

I'm pretty sure that it can be done with ICriteria, but I've only just started using NH so I can't seem to figure it out. I've basically got to the following:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Game>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Match"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("Score"))).List();
```

After that I've played around with various assortments of DetachedCriteria, but just seem to be going round in circles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the HQL world a single query does the trick...

```
var maxScore = session.CreateQuery(@"select sum(game.Score) 
                                     from Game game 
                                     group by game.Match
                                     order by sum(game.Score) desc")
                      .SetMaxResults(1)
                      .UniqueResult<long>();
```

Hope this helps..

Update: And for the Criteria world, may be there is a better result transformation but this just works :)

```
var max = (int)session.CreateCriteria<Game>("game")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                       .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("game.Match"))
                       .Add(Projections.Sum("game.Score"), "total"))
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("total"))
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)
    .UniqueResult<IDictionary>()["total"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually do it this way in SQL:

```
select top 1 Match.ID, sum(Game.Score) as total 
     from Game inner join Match
     on Game.Match_ID = Match.ID
     group by Match.ID order by total desc
```

group by is always tricky in Criteria/HQL: because a group by clause can only return the grouped column and aggregates of any other column.  Therefore it is impossible to return a whole entity from a group by clause, only the ID that you are grouping by and aggregates.

For this reason I usually do group by queries using native SQL like this:

```
ISQLQuery sqlQuery1 = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession().CreateSQLQuery("select Match.ID, sum(Game.Score) as total from Game inner join Match on Game.Match_ID = Match.ID group by match.ID order by total desc");
sqlQuery1.AddScalar("id", NHibernateUtil.Int32); //
sqlQuery1.AddScalar("total", NHibernateUtil.Int32);
sqlQuery1.SetMaxResults(1);    
var result = sqlQuery1.List();
```

Comment: I didn't even think about changing the query like that, thanks! I'm actually 'one of those' that would have previously done most things as stored procedures, so putting SQL in my code is probably not gonna happen. HQL scared me at first, but I think that it is pretty powerful, so I'll be going down that route I think.

Comment: Yeah!  Except the other guy pinched my SQL and made it into HQL!